# Encrypting home folder in Ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: 12.04, server, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

How can I encrypt the home folder in Ubuntu 12.04 server on-the-fly?

I tried this:

```
root@avo-server:/home/avo# ecryptfs-migrate-home -u avo
INFO:  Checking disk space, this may take a few moments.  Please be patient.
INFO:  Checking for open files in /home/avo
INFO:  The following files are in use:

    COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
    bash      1669 avo  cwd    DIR    8,1     4096 1185899 /home/avo
    sudo      1806   root  cwd    DIR    8,1     4096 1185899 /home/avo
    su        1807   root  cwd    DIR    8,1     4096 1185899 /home/avo
    bash      1808   root  cwd    DIR    8,1     4096 1185899 /home/avo
    ecryptfs- 1909   root  cwd    DIR    8,1     4096 1185899 /home/avo
    lsof      1931   root  cwd    DIR    8,1     4096 1185899 /home/avo
    sed       1932   root  cwd    DIR    8,1     4096 1185899 /home/avo
    lsof      1933   root  cwd    DIR    8,1     4096 1185899 /home/avo

ERROR:  Cannot proceed.
```

I'm getting `ERROR: Cannot proceed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You cannot encrypt your Home directory whilst you are logged in
- You need root privileges to encrypt a user’s Home directory.

So create a temporary administrator account to do the encryption of /home/avo/.

Comment: I already was using `sudo su` but another admin did the trick, thank you.